# Binary documents are not getting removed from SOLR when we unpublish the Page

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0, si4t, solr

We have a Web 8.5 .NET platform with DXA 2.0 and SI4T.

We have a web page with binary documents and when we publish the Page, the required fields and binary documents are indexed into SOLR successfully. But, when we unpublish the Page, only the Page gets deleted from SOLR but not the binary documents that were indexed separately.

As per our analysis, since the documents are getting indexed separately, on unpublish, it doesn’t look for those older documents and thus doesn’t remove them. So, basically, this is happening:

1. Page 1 has a RTF field which has pdf-v1.pdf linked in it
2. Page 1 is published and information is sent to Solr (we are using SI4T) where the page and pdf both get indexed
3. Content author goes and updated Page 1 with the same RTF field but updates the document to pdf-v2.pdf
4. Page 1 is published again and information is sent to Solr with same page and pdf-v2.pdf. But pdf-v1.pdf is NOT removed from solr

So now, both versions of the pdf are stored in solr and are searchable.

Did anyone face this issue before? Is there any workaround or setting that we are missing to enable this? Or any other pointers that might help us in fixing this issue?

The steps that we had followed for SI4T are [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-3752933E-141A-47F9-B483-5C2CCD9660BC)

Comment: As far as I know, SI4T will remove binaries when the last page or DCP referencing them has been unpublished. Perhaps there are still some published references?